# C++ template parse error

Tags: c++, parsing, templates, parse-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I have a static template method `test` in class `A` which takes a single `bool` template parameter. When I try to call the function like this:

```
x = A::test<true>(...);
```

The parser complains as it treats the `<` as the less than operator. How can I tell the compiler that this is a template instanciation rather than a less than oprator?

Comment: Is `A` a template parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A::template test<true>(...);
```

read [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: That should only be needed if `A` is a template parameter (or a dependent type of that).

Answer (score 2):

The `template` keyword removes the ambiguity.

```
x = A::template test<true>(...);
```